# Unhashable type: 'dict' error while trying to iterate over JSON files. How can I work around this?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am trying to iterate over a bunch of JSON dictionaries and copy their structure to a master JSON dictionary as the JSONs being iterated over can vary slightly in length, i.e. some have more entries than others.

This is the structure of my JSON files:

```py
{
  "General info": [
    {
      "section": "General info",
      "sub-section": "General info",
      "heading": "Personal Details",
      "field": "Full Name",
      "value": "John Doe"
    },
    {
      "section": "General info",
      "sub-section": "General info",
      "heading": "Personal Details",
      "field": "Address",
      "value": "69 Doe Lane"
    }
  ],
  "Disclosure": [
    {
      "section": "Disclosure",
      "sub-section": "Disclosure",
      "heading": "Agreement",
      "field": "Signed",
      "value": "Yes"
    },
    {
      "section": "Disclosure",
      "sub-section": "Disclosure",
      "heading": "Agreement",
      "field": "Signed2",
      "value": "Yes"
    }
  ],
  "Assets and Liabilities": [
    {
      "section": "Assets and Liabilities",
      "sub-section": "Assets",
      "heading": "Asset1",
      "field": "Asset value",
      "value": "£690"
    },
    {
      "section": "Assets and Liabilities",
      "sub-section": "Assets",
      "heading": "Asset1",
      "field": "Asset type",
      "value": "Current Account"
    },
    {
      "section": "Assets and Liabilities",
      "sub-section": "Assets",
      "heading": "Asset2",
      "field": "Asset value",
      "value": "£42"
    },
    {
      "section": "Assets and Liabilities",
      "sub-section": "Assets",
      "heading": "Asset2",
      "field": "Asset type",
      "value": "Stocks and Shares"
    }
  ]
}
```

Some of the JSON files will have more 'Assets' in the 'heading' key in the 'Assets and Liabilities' key. This is why I need to run through them all to get the maximum structure size prior to joining them all together, which is my ultimate goal.

I have got some code that I made to map out the shape of the JSON files, which iterates over them and adds missing keys to a master JSON. The issue comes when I hit the list of dictionaries at the lowest level. I cannot hash these dictionary entries like I do with the list above. What is the best way of doing this?

Here is my existing code, where the point of interest is in the last for loop:

```py
from ast import walk
import json, os
import pandas as pd

# first, set the master JSON as the first JSON file in the list of cases
master_JSON = r'''C:\Users\SJPJack\documents\JSON UAT\file1.json'''

# set the root dir - where all of my JSON files are
rootdir = "JSON UAT"

# open the master JSON
with open(master_JSON) as f:
    master_JSON = json.load(f)

# dump it for inspection
with open('master.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(master_JSON, f) # this is just so I can open it in the editor and track changes

# define a variable for deleting Client meeting summary from each JSON
deleted = 0

# build out our master JSON based on the list of case JSONs
# initiate loop for our JSON files
for subdir, dirs, file_names in os.walk(rootdir):
    for fname in file_names:
        json_path = os.path.join(subdir, fname)
        data = json.loads(open(json_path).read()) # load current JSON to data variable

        # iterate for each root key in the JSON 
        for category in list(data.keys()):
            if category not in list(master_JSON.keys()):
                master_JSON[category] = data[category] # add missing categories to our master JSON if missing

        # iterate for each root key in the JSON 
        for category in list(data.keys()):
            current_posts = data[category]
            master_posts = master_JSON[category]

            for current_post in current_posts:
                for field_name in list(current_post.keys()):
                    current_post['value'] = ""
                
                if current_post not in master_posts:
                    master_JSON[current_post] = current_post
```

Comment: Can you show us a smaller pair of example json as inputs and an example of what you want to see as the output?

Comment: Which line are you getting the error on? If it's 
on the last line, then `current_post` is a dictionary and cannot be used as a key ( also, it doesn't seem very meaningful to set the same thing as both key and value...did you mean yo type something else?)